# LUIS with bot framework unable to deserialize LUIS response

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

My call to LUIS encountered this error:

"Unable to deserialize LUI" with -      InnerException  {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0."}   System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException}

Any ideas on this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [Serialize] at the top of any class you use in your main dialog (including the dialog), that is because the communication between the bot and the user is via JSON, so any object should be serializable

Answer (score 0):

That happened for me when I was trying to call the built-in LUIS app (the one that does Cortana-like functions) using Bot Builder v.3.3.0.

When I removed that LuisModel, the error ceased.